# How to override keyboard shortcuts of application running in background?

Tags: javascript, windows

I have placed a keyboard shortcut ( Alt + Shift + T ) in my web application. I have used **preventDefault** with all the shortcuts. **It's working properly on Mac**, **but for windows, if Zoom is installed on it, it opens a layout to take a screenshot.**

Basically, Alt+Shift+T is a keyboard shortcut of **Zoom** to capture screenshots.

How can I **override** this zoom shortcut in my web-app? Is there any way to do it with JavaScript?